# Event for Selection.Load() in wpf RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, events, richtextbox

Is there a way to get an event raised when text is loaded into an RichTextBox using

```
richTextBox.Selection.Load(...)
```

Neither `TextChanged`, `SelectionChanged` and `TextInput` are raised nor `richTextBox.CommandBindings()` seems to offer an event.

Comment: is there any reason you can't do whatever you intend to do in the event handler right after you have called `Load`?

Comment: @mm8 The solution has a cache mechanism to speed up the RichTextBox. After a load, I have to clear the cache and create it again. Currently I have found several loads in the solution and I do not know if I found them all. The use of an event currently seems to be the once-reliable solution. (Or overwriting the load method)